# How to create an Xcode project for the Rust repository?

Tags: xcode, rust

I am a beginner wanting to contribute to open source, and I picked Rust as my first project to do so. I want to create an Xcode project with all the Rust source files so that I can edit code, attach to running process and debug some of the issues.

I am stuck at creating the Xcode project. I am following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942059/creating-an-xcode-project-with-existing-code), and everything goes fine until Xcode freezes in indexing:

[image: screenshot]

What's gone wrong? How can I build the project?

Please comment if this is the right approach to get started. Should I be using other methods/tools to get debugging started with Rust?

I am on macOS 10.12.2 running Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: Huh... I don't even know if any of the core contributors uses an IDE to hack on Rust itself. Personally, I just use my preferred text editor and do all the compilation from the command line. I don't see why you couldn't use Xcode for editing the text, but does it even have Rust syntax highlighting? Then you'd have to figure out how to connect the Rust build system with whatever Xcode supports. FWIW, *I* wouldn't try it.

Comment: Use tags for what your question is **about**. This question, as currently worded, asks nothing **about** Make, CMake, or Open Source; they appear incidental.

Comment: do you plan to mix rust with cocoa? Then xcode makes sense to me. There's [xi-editor](https://github.com/google/xi-editor) a text editor (early alpha stage) which mixes rust with cocoa, maybe this could help you as a starting point. Otherwise: [areweideyet.com](https://areweideyet.com/) shows which IDEs support rust best. Personally I chose for IntelliJ.

Comment: and btw: welcome to Rust, glad you're joining :)