# no .xcodeproj file when downloading ZIP on github

Tags: xcode, github

I am trying to put my GitHub project into Xcode.  When I download from GitHub the zip file does not contain any .xcodeproj file.

Also, even when I am logged in on GitHub on xcode there is no "open in Xcode" option when I clone/download.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see any .xcodeproj on GitHub, that means no such file was added/committed and pushed to that repository.

You would need to [create an XCode project with existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5942059/6309), which would generate that file.